# How to make a property of a class optional in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to make a shopping list application with a RecyclerView in Kotlin. Users have to define an item name and they have an optional checkbox for 'Quantity' and 'Price'. Since RecyclerView needs a dataset to display data, I've figured it would be easiest to populate it from a list of  objects. However, I don't know how to add a certain class property to that list ONLY if an option was selected on the checkbox.

My initial idea was to create separate lists, but the object still has the same properties so that wouldn't help. If I define a second constructor and assign its parameters to the properties of a class, would that make it 'optional' or I would get an error if I tried to display a list where not all properties have been input?

Perhaps I should define a mutableListOf Strings, get only the properties I need and then use that for a dataset?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean nullable properties?

Comment: If I set the property value of a class as "null", what would happen once I try to add my object to a list that has a type of that object? Would it ignore it since it's null or crash the app?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. List contains objects, objects contains properties. List does not care about the properties of objects it holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic implementation would be to have a `var` property for each configurable aspect in your Adapter, and use `onBindView` to selectively hide/show those elements of the item view layout.

You can define a delegate that causes the adapter to refresh when these settings change:

```
class AdapterSetting<T>(private var value: T): ReadWriteProperty<RecyclerView.Adapter<*>, T> {
    override fun getValue(thisRef: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>, property: KProperty<*>): T = value

    override fun setValue(thisRef: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        this.value = value
        thisRef.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

fun <T> RecyclerView.Adapter<*>.adapterSetting(initialValue: T) = AdapterSetting(initialValue)
```

Then your adapter could look like this:

```
class MyItemAdapter: ListAdapter<MyItem, MyItemViewHolder>(MyItem.DIFF_CALLBACK) {
    var isShowQuantity by adapterSetting(true)
    var isShowPrice by adapterSetting(true)
    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyItemViewHolder
        = MyItemViewHolder(MyListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        with (holder.binding) {
            nameTextView.text = item.name
            priceTextView.isVisible = isShowPrice
            if (isShowPrice) {
                priceTextView.text = item.price.toPlainString()
            }
            quantityTextView.isVisible = isShowQuantity
            if (isShowQuantity) {
                quantityTextView.text = item.quantity.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the user changes these settings, you change the property of the adapter, and it will refresh the view.

Comment: That's it.
Thank you.

Comment: EDIT: Wouldn't this cause scalability issues in the long run if the dataset is too big? I mean you are basically adding all that data and hiding it, isn't there a way to filter which data you are adding to the list in the first place?

Comment: You mean you're concerned about the memory used by the extra two properties in each list item? If that's the case, you could create separate adapters. It would take a lot of items for this to make much difference. The Adapter itself would never be the bottleneck on your performance or memory because it only ever generates enough views to fit on the screen plus a couple extra.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, you are one of the rare people who get what I'm trying to say instantly. Helped me a bunch to resolve this "issue".

Answer (score 0):

Will be great if you can provide some code snippet to clarify what you want.

Besides that, I can suggest you to try to define your property as "lateinit var" - the property will exist but just will be initialized when you populate it. Maybe it can help your use case.

```
private lateinit var myList: List<Example>

init { 
  if(boolean) {
        myList = listOf(Example(""), Example(""), Example(""))
    }
}
```

Don't forget to check if your list is initialized when you need it, to avoid exceptions at runtime.